# How do I port asynchronous calls from app engine to tornado?

Tags: google-app-engine, asynchronous, tornado

App-engine asynchronous example:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, "http://www.google.com/")

try:
    result = rpc.get_result()
    if result.status_code == 200:
        text = result.content
        # ...
except urlfetch.DownloadError:
    raise
return text
```

How do I do this in tornado? I've tried (using [swirl](http://code.naeseth.com/swirl/)) with something like:

```
import swirl

http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
uri = 'http://www.google.com/'

try:
    response = yield lambda cb: http.fetch(uri, cb)
    if response.code == 200:
        text = result.content
        # ...
except tornado.httpclient.HTTPError:
    raise
return text
```

But I get a Syntax Error because I can't have a return and a yield in the same function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that swirl doesn't provide any facilities for returning values from coroutines. Other frameworks that use this pattern, like NDB, let you raise a special 'return exception', or yield a return value, but swirl doesn't appear to provide this option. You'll need to restructure your coroutines to not return a value, instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Tornado `RequestHandler` that is marked with the `@gen.coroutine` decorator, you can make use of `Future`s and the `yield` keyword to accomplish what you want.

For the simple case of returning the result of an asynchronous HTTP fetch, the `AsyncHTTPClient.fetch` method suffices:

```py
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        def handle_response(response):
            if response.error:
                print("Error: %s" % response.error)
            else:
                self.write(response.body)

        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        yield http_client.fetch('http://www.google.com/', handle_response)
```

To create a function that returns an arbitrary result asynchronously, you'll want to create your own `Future` object to return to the caller. Let's say your function needs to make an async web fetch before returning a custom value:

```py
def get_async_result():
    future = Future()

    def handle_response(response):
        if response.error:
            future.set_exception(Exception("Yikes"))
        else:
            future.set_result("I, for one, welcome our new robot overlords.")
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    http_client.fetch('http://www.google.com/', handle_response)
    return future

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        result = yield get_async_result()
        print result    # "I, for one, welcome our new robot overlords."
        # rest of handler here...
```

The `yield` statement in your RequestHandler logically blocks until the returned `Future` has been completed, providing you with the result (or an exception) directly.

(Note that [as explained here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#wsgi-and-google-app-engine) you cannot Tornado's async mechanisms in Google App Engine.)